# How to add a new value to the custom options?

Tags: magento-1.4

I want to extend the custom options feature of Magento. I cant use any of the existing ones like sku or title. I need a completely new one, called "path". What are the steps to add it? It seems adding a row to catalog_product_option is part of it, but I think there is much more to do?

Answer (score 1):

I did something super simple in the past that you may or may not find useful. Our situation was the need for an Auto Complete field in new text options. So in the design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\options\type\text.phtml, this is the new javascript var for OptionTemplateText:

```
OptionTemplateText = '<table class="border" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">'+
    '<tr class="headings">'+
        '<th class="type-price"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Price') ?></th>'+
        '<th class="type-type"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Price Type') ?></th>'+
        '<th class="type-sku"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU') ?></th>'+
        '<th class="type-last last"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Max Characters') ?> </th>'+
        '<th class="type-last last"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Auto Complete') ?> </th>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td><input type="text" class="input-text validate-number product-option-price" id="product_option_{{option_id}}_price" name="product[options][{{option_id}}][price]" value="{{price}}"></td>'+
        '<td><?php echo $this->getPriceTypeSelectHtml() ?>{{checkboxScopePrice}}</td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" class="input-text" name="product[options][{{option_id}}][sku]" value="{{sku}}"></td>'+
        '<td class="type-last last"><input type="text" class="input-text validate-zero-or-greater" name="product[options][{{option_id}}][max_characters]" value="{{max_characters}}"></td>'+
        '<td class="type-last last"><input type="text" class="input-text" name="product[options][{{option_id}}][auto_complete]" value="{{auto_complete}}"> * service URL</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
'</table>';
```

Then we overwrote the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option with our own quick class using this rewrite:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>MyNameSpace_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option</catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

And here's the whole class.

```
class MyNameSpace_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/edit/options/option.phtml');
}

public function getOptionValues() {
    $optionsArr = array_reverse($this->getProduct()->getOptions(), true);

    if (!$this->_values) {
        $values = array();
        $scope = (int) Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_PRICE_SCOPE);
        foreach ($optionsArr as $option) {
            /* @var $option Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option */

            $this->setItemCount($option->getOptionId());

            $value = array();

            $value['id'] = $option->getOptionId();
            $value['item_count'] = $this->getItemCount();
            $value['option_id'] = $option->getOptionId();
            $value['title'] = $this->htmlEscape($option->getTitle());
            $value['type'] = $option->getType();
            $value['is_require'] = $option->getIsRequire();
            $value['sort_order'] = $option->getSortOrder();

            if ($this->getProduct()->getStoreId() != '0') {
                $value['checkboxScopeTitle'] = $this->getCheckboxScopeHtml($option->getOptionId(), 'title', is_null($option->getStoreTitle()));
                $value['scopeTitleDisabled'] = is_null($option->getStoreTitle())?'disabled':null;
            }

            if ($option->getGroupByType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_GROUP_SELECT) {

                $i = 0;
                $itemCount = 0;
                foreach ($option->getValues() as $_value) {
                    /* @var $_value Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Value */
                    $value['optionValues'][$i] = array(
                        'item_count' => max($itemCount, $_value->getOptionTypeId()),
                        'option_id' => $_value->getOptionId(),
                        'option_type_id' => $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                        'title' => $this->htmlEscape($_value->getTitle()),
                        'price' => $this->getPriceValue($_value->getPrice(), $_value->getPriceType()),
                        'price_type' => $_value->getPriceType(),
                        'sku' => $this->htmlEscape($_value->getSku()),
                        'sort_order' => $_value->getSortOrder(),
                    );

                    if ($this->getProduct()->getStoreId() != '0') {
                        $value['optionValues'][$i]['checkboxScopeTitle'] = $this->getCheckboxScopeHtml($_value->getOptionId(), 'title', is_null($_value->getStoreTitle()), $_value->getOptionTypeId());
                        $value['optionValues'][$i]['scopeTitleDisabled'] = is_null($_value->getStoreTitle())?'disabled':null;
                        if ($scope == Mage_Core_Model_Store::PRICE_SCOPE_WEBSITE) {
                            $value['optionValues'][$i]['checkboxScopePrice'] = $this->getCheckboxScopeHtml($_value->getOptionId(), 'price', is_null($_value->getstorePrice()), $_value->getOptionTypeId());
                            $value['optionValues'][$i]['scopePriceDisabled'] = is_null($_value->getStorePrice())?'disabled':null;
                        }
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
            } else {
                $value['price'] = $this->getPriceValue($option->getPrice(), $option->getPriceType());
                $value['price_type'] = $option->getPriceType();
                $value['sku'] = $this->htmlEscape($option->getSku());
                $value['max_characters'] = $option->getMaxCharacters();
                $value['auto_complete'] = $option->getAutoComplete();
                $value['file_extension'] = $option->getFileExtension();
                $value['image_size_x'] = $option->getImageSizeX();
                $value['image_size_y'] = $option->getImageSizeY();
                if ($this->getProduct()->getStoreId() != '0' && $scope == Mage_Core_Model_Store::PRICE_SCOPE_WEBSITE) {
                    $value['checkboxScopePrice'] = $this->getCheckboxScopeHtml($option->getOptionId(), 'price', is_null($option->getStorePrice()));
                    $value['scopePriceDisabled'] = is_null($option->getStorePrice())?'disabled':null;
                }
            }
            $values[] = new Varien_Object($value);
        }
        $this->_values = $values;
    }

    return $this->_values;
}
}
```

The last piece to this puzzle was this little bitty sql statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_option` ADD COLUMN `auto_complete` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `max_caharacters`;
```